Categorical characterization of Hausdorff completion of a uniform space
I know that a function between uniform spaces $\varphi:X\to X'$ is an Hausdorff completion if and only if:

$X'$ is complete Hausdorff uniform space;
$\varphi$ is a dense and initial uniformly continuous function.

This characterization can be generalized?
More precisely, let $\Gamma:\mathscr U\to\mathscr S$ be a topological functor and $\mathscr U'\subseteq\mathscr U$ be a full subcategory.
A structured arrow $u:U\to U'$ is reflective if and only if is generating and initial (respect to $\Gamma$)?
I attempted to prove that such a structured arrow is universal using a method similar to the one seen in the proof of the taut lift theorem, but I wasn't able to reach a conclusion.
